# Deleting a product from shopping cart

Tags: php, sql, shopping-cart, cart

I have a shopping cart which works almost perfectly. However, I want to be able to delete products without having to set the quantity to 0. So each product in the cart has its own delete button with name='delete'.

Now I have this code on top of the page. I already have an 'Update cart'-button, which is the upper part of the code. The lower part of the code is the code for the delete button.

```html
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  
  foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
   if($val==0) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
   }else{
    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
   }
  }
  
 }
 
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  
  foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
   }
  }

?>

<h2>Your shopping cart</h2>
 <p class="lead">Since the beginning, Movingscales™ has become one of the world's biggest scale models sellers with thousands of orders a year. We sell scale models in every kind of transportation, from motorcycles to planes. We don't just sell these products, but we are also involved in the production and design of the models. This is the reason why our products are premium-quality scale models. You can buy the products from our Movingscales™-collection through our online store or in one of our stores around the world.</p>
<form method="post" action="thecollection.php?page=cart">
    
 <table class="table table-striped">
     
  <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total price</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php
  
   $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE productCode IN (";
     
     foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
      $sql.="'".$id."',";
     }
     
     $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY productName ASC";
     $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
     $totalprice=0;
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['productCode']]['quantity']*$row['buyPrice'];
      $totalprice+=$subtotal;
     ?>
      <tr class="registerform">
          <td><?php echo $row['productName'] ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['productCode'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['productCode']]['quantity'] ?>" /></td>
          <td>€<?php echo $row['buyPrice'] ?></td>
          <td>€<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['productCode']]['quantity']*$row['buyPrice'] ?></td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-login" type="submit" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></button></td>
      </tr>
     <?php
      
     }
  ?>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="5"><h4>Total price: <i>€<?php echo $totalprice ?></i></h4></td>
     </tr>
  
 </table>
 <br />
 <a href="thecollection.php?productline=all&scale=all&minimum=10&maximum=110&sortby=Name (A...Z)" class="btn btn-login">Continue shopping</a>
 <button class="btn btn-login" type="submit" name="submit">Update cart</button>
 <button class="btn btn-login" type="submit" name="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Why isn't it working? I want to basically unset it whenever you click on the delete button.

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: @jeroen I edited my post with the whole code for the cart.php page.

Answer (score 0):

If every product has its own delete button, how do you tell which button is clicked?

To delete products in your cart, you need be able to tell which product is selected.

You can replace your delete button with a link:

```
<a href="/store/cart.php?act=delete&productid=$productid">delete</a>
```

Or

add a hidden value in your form:

```
<input type=hidden name=product_to_delete value=0>  
...
<input type=button name=deletebtn   onclick="javascript:document.cart_form.product_to_delete.value=$productid; document.cart_form.submit()"; >
```

Or

You can add a checkbox for each product, and one "Delete" button for the whole list, when you click the Delete button, your php should delete each selected product id.

Comment: I have edited my post with the whole cart.php code. Can you give me an answer? I'm completely confused.